# Binding text to a textbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm binding text to my textbox, but the name of my binding begins with an underscore. This is how it exists in the database. Problem is it doesn't seem to work. The data is there, but the binding name doesn't turn red in the XAML (it usually does). If I replace it with a different field (one that doesn't start with an underscore) it seems to work okay.

Can anyone recommend a good workaround for this? I'm not able to edit the database fields.

Thanks.

Comment: Name with an underscore should be fine, can you post XAML binding code? Aslo try to put <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" /> and see what is displayed on screen and then post here as update

Comment: Can you post the related code ?

Comment: Sure, can do. [Here's the working version](http://i.imgur.com/OWyhs.jpg) and [here's the not working version](http://i.imgur.com/wnuNZ.jpg). Notice the colour change, even though the conversion to jpg has drained some of the colour away.

Also, while you're at it, if you have any idea why changing the grid rows does nothing to the on screen appearance, that would be a great bonus.

Comment: are you sure that _userName is public ?

Comment: Check your `PropertyChanged` call to make sure it's `"_userName"`.

Comment: make sure it is public and accessible and try {Binding Path=_userName}

Comment: Is `_userName` a property or a field?

Comment: The binding name probably hasn't turned red because the VS designer assumes property names don't begin with an underscore.  You may well have found a corner-case oddity with the VS designer, but I can't believe that this minor cosmetic issue would cause problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical issues in binding to a property starting with an underscore. I have created a small demo where I bind to a property starting with an underscore - you can download it here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4243120/demos/Binding%20to%20Property%20with%20Underscore.zip

In the output window in Visual Studio you can see any binding exceptions occurring in your app. As an alternative you can try to add a converter to your binding to see if it is hit at all.

Comment: The problem was my own foolishness. I was attempting to bind the private variable name and not the public accessor. Even so, I appreciate your time.